# Time machine - does it do its own encryption, beyond volume encryption?

Tags: time-machine, encryption, filevault

Time Machine allows encrypted backups. Where does this encryption happen? Is the data written to files inside the time machine volume encrypted? If so: does this mean it's possible to end up with "doubly encrypted" data, if my disk partition is encrypted (i.e. by activating encryption in disk utility when making a partition)? And if that's possible, where should I most efficiently use encryption - should I do time machine encryption only, or volume encryption only?